# Remote Desktop Connection error while trying to connect to a t2.micro instance of Windows SQL Server on Amazon Web Services

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, instance, rdp

I created a free t2.micro instance of Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Base - ami-63489d00.  I am unable to connect to the instance after downloading the remote desktop file.  I have ensured that inbound RDP connections are allowed - in the security settings. And also ensured that no firewall on my network blocks the connection.

I keep getting the error

> "Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of the following reasons
>
> 1) Remote access to the server isn't enabled
>   2) The remote computer is turned off
>   3) The remote computer isn't available on the network"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public IP address of Amazon AWS instance will change after every shutdown. So, First, look at the EC2 console on current IP. And Second, You must allow 3389 port (RDP protocol) into security group of the instance. Please, check this too. And finally I recommend the most for you check your own firewall and network rules for allowed rules for RDP. For example, try to connect to instance from few endpoints in another network (location like home, school, internet cafe).
That's all.